# strange issues of live reload in angular 6

Tags: angular, livereload

I'm using angular 6 and I have a issue in live reload. The thing is live reload in working when I update app files.

For example: 
If I update `app.module.ts` then my live reload works.

But when I update my any component file, It is not detect my new changes.

I'm using this project environment.

`Angular CLI: 6.0.3
 Node: 8.10.0
 OS: linux x64
 Angular: 6.0.3`.

Comment: Maybe IDE is not saving file? Try focus out of the window - I have to do such thing sometimes with IntelliJ

Comment: @Antoniossss I'm using VSCode and how can I know that my IDE is not saving file ? And my IDE shows file is saved.

Comment: Try `ng serve` and edit using notepad.

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks for your reply. I run my app by `sudo` and it works for me.

Comment: so its permission issue. Probbably component has different owner than module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run by `sudo ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200`. And it's worked for me.